# How to order by with union in SQL to make first select query value first?

Tags: sql, oracle

In this query:

```
SELECT NM, DEP_CD FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD='1100' and (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BBS_TABLE WHERE UP_DEP_CD = '1100') > 0
UNION
SELECT NM, DEP_CD FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD '1110'
```

First
`select query ( SELECT NM, DEP_CD FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD='1100'`
and
`(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BBS_TABLE WHERE UP_DEP_CD = '1100') > 0)`
always returns 1 result.
I want to put this one first in the result values, but there are no regular rules for results so I couldn't use order by.

How can I put the first query's result in the first row?
I use oracle db.

Comment: As it stands, the query hardly makes sense. There is a missing operator in `WHERE DEP_CD '1110'`. Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your requirement.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option to do it.

Define a dummy column as rnk, giving the first query rnk=1 and the one below the union as 2.
After that order by the rnk column

```
SELECT NM, DEP_CD,1 as rnk FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD='1100' and (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BBS_TABLE WHERE UP_DEP_CD = '1100') > 0
UNION
SELECT NM, DEP_CD,2 as rnk FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD '1110'
ORDER BY 3 ASC
```

In case you dont want the final output to have the rnk field then use an outer query as follows

```
select x.NM,x.DEP_CD from (
    SELECT NM, DEP_CD,1 as rnk FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD='1100' and (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BBS_TABLE WHERE UP_DEP_CD = '1100') > 0
    UNION
    SELECT NM, DEP_CD,2 as rnk FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD '1110'
)x
ORDER BY x.rnk ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use `union`?  Why not just use:

```
SELECT NM, DEP_CD
FROM EMP
WHERE DEP_CD = '1100' 
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BBS_TABLE WHERE UP_DEP_CD = '1100') DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `order by` on `DEP_CD` as follows:

```
SELECT NM, DEP_CD FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD='1100' and (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BBS_TABLE WHERE UP_DEP_CD = '1100') > 0
UNION
SELECT NM, DEP_CD FROM EMP WHERE DEP_CD = '1110'
ORDER BY DEP_CD; -- this line
```